# Tracking (microtype) causes different results within \makebox

Tags: luatex, small-caps, microtype, letterspacing

Why is the tracking for small caps text different in `\makebox` and how can I get an equal result?

```latex
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[%
   tracking=smallcaps,%
]{microtype}%
\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{150}%for demonstration purposes

\begin{document}
\textsc{ABCDE}

\makebox[25mm][l]{\textsc{ABCDE}}

\end{document}
```

Output of `\listfiles`:

```
*File List*
    book.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
    bk10.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2021-01-09 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2021-02-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-luatex.def    2021-02-06 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
xparse-2020-10-01.sty    
fontspec-luatex.sty    2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
fontspec.cfg
microtype.sty    2020/12/07 v2.8 Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
microtype-luatex.def    2020/12/07 v2.8 Definitions specific to luatex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2020/12/07 v2.8 microtype main configuration file (RS)
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg    2013/03/13 v1.0 microtype config. file: Latin Modern 
Roman (RS)
 ***********
```

Comment: Looks like the tracking is applied a second time when unhboxing. `\setbox0=\hbox{\textsc{ABCDE}} \hbox to 25mm{\unhbox0\hss}`

Comment: It seems to be a bug with microtype, because I can't reproduce it with LuaTeX primitives: http://dpaste.com/5EC4N4GBB (expires in 10 days)

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I should probably report this to the `microtype` author.

Comment: @Martin That's a known luaotfload issue (https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/167)

Comment: Ah, okay. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is fixed in v3.18 of `luaotfload` released yesterday. Thank you Marcel.